# MYSQL top N rows from multiple table join

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Like, there is top keyword in sql server 2005, how to select top 1 row in mysql if i have join on multiple table & want to retrieve extreme of each ID/column. Limit restricts the no. of row returns so it can't solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, the question is not very clear. I just guessed

Comment: The question is not very clear, but I'm guessing it's another case of the `greatest-n-per-group` problem that comes up frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  v.*
FROM    document d
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    version v
        WHERE   v.document = d.id
        ORDER BY
                v.revision DESC
        ) v
```

or

```
SELECT  v.*
FROM    document d
LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.id ORDER BY revision DESC)
        FROM    version
        ) v
ON      v.document = d.id
        AND v.rn = 1
```

The latter is more efficient if your documents usually have few revisions and you need to select all or almost all documents; the former is more efficient if the documents have many revisions or you need to select just a small subset of documents.

**Update:**

Sorry, didn't notice the question is about `MySQL`.

In `MySQL`, you do it this way:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    document d
LEFT JOIN
        version v
ON      v.id = 
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    version vi
        WHERE   vi.document = d.document
        ORDER BY
                vi.document DESC, vi.revision DESC, vi.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create a composite index on `version (document, revision, id)` for this to work fast.

Comment: MySQL does not support `APPLY` or `ROW_NUMBER()` (window functions).

Comment: Later reply works but what if for some rows i have only one record ex: version have only one record for a particular docID in that case query retrieve no rows for that ID. Sorry for late reply/comment

Comment: @deepesh: could you please post the sample data: records for the document and version which you think should work but they don't?

Comment: Quassnoi : thanks a ton it works quite well actually there was inconsistency in database. Once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, top doesn't solve your problem either. top is exactly equivalent to limit. What you are looking for is aggregate functions, like max() or min() if you want the extremes. for example:

```
select link_id, max(column_a), min(column_b) from table_a a, table_b b 
where a.link_id = b.link_id group by link_id
```